# WITH clause in HIVE

Tags: hive

In below code **temp1** is used 2 times, so hive will be execute the select query in temp1 twice? or just once?

```
with temp1(
select distinct b as b, f, t1.id as id,       
from
   table1 t1
join 
   table2 t2 on (t1.id=t2.id)
),
agg_tbl as 
(
 select
     max(abc) as maxabc,
     tbl.t
 from(
   select
        count(*) as cnt,  b, f
  from
       temp1
  group by
       b, f
  ) tbl group by tbl.t
), 
class_tbl as
(select
      case 
         when bp = 1 then 'abc'
         when bp = 2 then 'xyz'
     end as class,
    bp
 from
 ( select
       count(b) as bcount, bp
    from
       temp1
   group by  bp
 )tbl
)
```

If that is the case, then using temporary tables will make sense.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not an expert in Hive, but you may have an issue with using the CTE `temp1` more than once.

Comment: It depends also on execution engine: MR or TEZ.

Comment: @leftjoin execution engine is TEZ